# reformat text in perl

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file of 1000 lines, each line in the format

```
filename dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

I want to convert it to read

```
filename mmddhhmm.ss
```

been attempting to do this in perl and awk - no success - would appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do a simple regular expression replacement if the format is really fixed:

```
s|(..)/(..)/.... (..):(..):(..)$|$2$1$3$4.$5|
```

I used `|` as a separator so that I do not need to escape the slashes.

You can use this with Perl on the shell in place:

```
perl -pi -e 's|(..)/(..)/.... (..):(..):(..)$|$2$1$3$4.$5|' file
```

(Look up the option descriptions with `man perlrun`).

Comment: so just perl - e s|(..)/(..)/.... (..):(..):(..)$|$2$1$3$4.$5| file?

sorry if I'm being a bit dense here

Comment: @paul44 yes, that will send the results to the terminal. To "update" the file, you need to redirect the output to a different file, and then rename it over the original. Don't forget to quote the string too though, to stop the shell interpreting all the special characters itself.

Comment: perl -e does not return anything.  perl -pe just acts like I'm catting the file to STDOUT - no changes.  I'm running:

    perl -pe "s|(..)/(..)/(....) (..):(..):(..)$|$2$1$3$4$5.$6|" testlist

to get the year too.

Comment: If you want to have the year too, _please_ put it in front: yyyy-mm-dd; do not mix descending and ascending order of the units.

Answer (score 1):

Another somehow ugly approach: foreach line of code ($str here) you get from the file do something like this:

```
my $str = 'filename 26/12/2010 21:09:12';

my @arr1 = split(' ',$str);
my @arr2 = split('/',$arr1[1]);
my @arr3 = split(':',$arr1[2]);

my $day = $arr2[0]; 
my $month = $arr2[1]; 
my $year = $arr2[2];

my $hours = $arr3[0]; 
my $minutes = $arr3[1]; 
my $seconds = $arr3[2];

print $arr1[0].' '.$month.$day.$year.$hours.$minutes.'.'.$seconds;
```

Comment: Maybe ugly, but understandable to any non-expert.

Comment: so can I 
    open (FILELIST, "list)
    while $str = <FILELIST>  ?

Comment: I would just use `split /[\/:\s]/, $str`

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your file to a perl script with:

```
while( my line = <> ){
    if ( $line =~ /(\S+)\s+\(d{2})\/(\d{2})/\d{4}\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/ ) {
        print $1 . " " . $3 . $2 . $4 . $5 . '.' . $6;
    }
}
```

Redirect the output however you want.
This says match line to:
(non-whitespace>=1)whitespace>=1(2digits)/(2digits)/4digits
whitepsace>=1(2digits):(2digits):(2digits)

Capture groups are in () numbered 1 to 6 left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's|/[0-9]{4} ||; s|/||; s/://; s/:/./' file.txt
```

- delete the year `/yyyy`
- delete the remaining slash
- delete the first colon
- change the remaining colon to a dot

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{split($2,d,"/"); split($3,t,":"); print $1, d[1] d[2] t[1] t[2] "." t[3]}'
```